# Trying to install graphql package with node

Tags: node.js, npm, graphql, node-modules

> ```
> npm ERR! code ENOSELF
> npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "graphql" under a package
> npm ERR! also called "graphql". Did you name your project the same
> npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! For more information, see:
> ```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `name` prop on your `package.json` to anything but `graphql`

Answer (score 0):

Edit package.json

```json
{
      "name": "graphql-basic", # --> change name but don't graphql
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
          "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
          "express": "^4.17.1",
          "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
          "graphql": "^15.4.0"
      }
}
```